# python pprint shows data but print shows empty value

Tags: python

I am trying to get a serial port output. When I am trying with pprint it will show in bytecode but it will turn empty while I am trying with print inside while.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=5)
while True:
    x = ser.readline()
    print x
    pprint.pprint(x)
```

Comment: What is the output that `pprint` displays?

Comment: \xfc'|\xff\xe9\xff\x06\xff\xf8\xf9\xd6\xfd+\xafv\xe6\xa88\xda4\xfe

Comment: `print type(x); print len(x); print unicode(x)`?

Comment: how do I get the value of \xfc'|\xff\xe9\xff\x06\xff\xf8\xf9\xd6\xfd+\xafv\xe6\xa88\xda4\xfe ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference you're seeing is because `pprint.pprint` is safely taking the `repr` of the object while `print` is taking the `str` of the object.

Consider this example:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'repr'
  def __str__(self):
    return 'str'

print Foo()  # prints 'str', not 'repr'
```

If you want to see how pprint.pprint is implemented, take a look at the help page.  On my OSX laptop I see this (with ipython):

```
Python 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import pprint

In [2]: help(pprint)

Help on module pprint:

NAME
    pprint - Support to pretty-print lists, tuples, & dictionaries recursively.

FILE
    //anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pprint.py
...
```

From here, I know the source for `pprint` is in `//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pprint.py`.

To view it in ipython, I can open it like this:

```
In [3]: !less //anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pprint.py
```

From here we can search through the code in the file to trace back how `pprint.pprint` actually works.

Cutting to the chase, `pprint.pprint` uses a complex and careful `repr` function to give you your bytecode.